# Difference between EXEC() and sp_executesql with no parameters?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I just learned about the new sp_executesql stored procedure.  I like the fact that there's a way to execute parameterized code from within SQL Server.

But, I'm wondering what the difference is between using the sp_executesql stored procedure when you don't have any parameters versus just calling EXEC directly.  Also, is there a performance implication?

```
exec('select * from line_segment')
exec sp_executesql N'select * from line_segment'
```

Also, is there a difference between 2005 and 2008 or do they handle these the same?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548090/dynamic-sql-execsql-versus-exec-sp-executesqlsql/548103#548103

Answer (score 13, accepted):

sp_executesql supports parameterisation, whereas EXEC only accepts a string.

Only performance differences that may arise are due to the parameterisation i.e. a parameterised sp_executesql call is more likely to have a reusable cached plan. An EXEC call is likely to lead to lots of single use space wasters in the plan cache.

Comment: So, when sp_executesql is called with no parameters, it's just as efficient as EXEC?

Comment: If both produce the same execution plan then yes, the performance must be the same. You could argue that parameter sniffing might cause problems with sp_executesql but the causes and solutions would be the same as for stored procs.

Answer (score 1):

This helped me to crack the interview that's why I'm posting to help someone for the same.

[image]

*Good luck!*

Comment: 2. sp_executesql Is save for sql injection.  3. White space is irrelevant. 4.any plan is cached, but parameterised plans are reused.    
Please do not  insert text as image. It is not searchable, not copied for paste, not editable